# fzf behavior changes when capturing its output

Tags: fzf

The following command works fine as expected:

```
find ~ -type f | fzf -m --preview-window=up:30% --header "ctrl-f: selected all and exit" --bind "enter:execute(less {})" --bind "ctrl-f:select-all+accept"
```

But if I add `>outfile.txt` or `| xclip` to the end of this command, all `--bind` options that contain `execute` action are ignored. Is this a known fault? Is there a way around it?

Comment: You need `find -print0` and `fzf --read0` to handle arbitrary file paths, and make sure `$SHELL` refers to a Bourne-like shell when using `fzf`'s `execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all `--bind` options that contain `execute` action are ignored

I don't think so. In my tests `less` does start. It does not behave as you expect because it inherits the redirected stdout from `fzf`. `less` reads keystrokes from the terminal even if its stdin is something else (so redirected input is not a problem); but it prints to its stdout (so redirected output is a problem, the problem). If you want to see what `less` prints and still redirect output from `fzf`, tell `less` specifically to use `/dev/tty` as its stdout:

```
find ~ -type f \
| fzf -m --preview-window=up:30% --header "ctrl-f: selected all and exit" \
--bind "enter:execute(less {} >/dev/tty)" \
--bind "ctrl-f:select-all+accept" >outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. This is very interesting and exactly what I want. Odd that I have not seen this important point in any of the fzf documentations.